# Jython scoping issue?

Tags: jython, nameerror

Even though I import Swing classes at the start of the script, when I try to access them from a function called by a button click, Jython tells me:

> NameError: global name 'JOptionPane' is not defined

```
from javax.swing import JButton, JFrame, JOptionPane


def testfunc(event):

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(None, "CLICKED")

frame = JFrame('Hello!',  alwaysOnTop = True, locationRelativeTo = None,   size = (300, 300)   )
button = JButton('Click Me!', actionPerformed=testfunc)

frame.add(button)

frame.visible = True
```

This is a very simple Jython test script running inside a data modeling tool - but for this example, there is nothing specific to that tool which is referenced.

Basically, everything I import, including, for example, datetime, becomes "undefined" when I call it from a function that handles the actionPerformed for a Swing component.  If I add another import statement to the beginning of the testfunc function, then Jython "sees" the JOptionPane.

If I call testfunc any other way, it does not throw the error and instead displays the JOptionPane as expected.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It works for me (Jython 2.7.1).

Comment: This is what I am afraid of, mzjn.  The company who makes the tool we're using is saying this is just "normal Jython behavior" but it doesn't seem right to me.